# Playbook not use sudo command - Ansible Semaphore in Docker Container

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-playbook, devops

So

I'm learning DevOps tools. I installed Ansible Semaphore in a Docker container on my home server and created playbooks. I created a sudo user on a remote server and added an SSH key. However, my playbook, intended to install UFW and open ports 22, 80, and 443, fails because the user isn't root and lacks permission to execute the command. Why is this happening?

```
---
- name: Installiere und konfiguriere UFW Firewall
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Installiere UFW
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        name: ufw
        state: present

    - name: Erlaube Port 22 (SSH)
      ansible.builtin.ufw:
        rule: allow
        port: '22'
        proto: tcp

    - name: Erlaube Port 80 (HTTP)
      ansible.builtin.ufw:
        rule: allow
        port: '80'
        proto: tcp

    - name: Erlaube Port 443 (HTTPS)
      ansible.builtin.ufw:
        rule: allow
        port: '443'
        proto: tcp

    - name: Aktiviere UFW
      ansible.builtin.ufw:
        state: enabled
        policy: deny
        direction: incoming

    - name: Reboote den Server
      ansible.builtin.reboot:
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mysql:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:8.0
    hostname: mysql
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    volumes:
      - semaphore-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: semaphore
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
  semaphore:
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '${SEMAPHORE_PORT:-3000}:3000'
    image: semaphoreui/semaphore:latest
    environment:
      SEMAPHORE_DB_USER: "${DB_USER}"
      SEMAPHORE_DB_PASS: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      SEMAPHORE_DB_HOST: mysql 
      SEMAPHORE_DB_PORT: 3306
      SEMAPHORE_DB_DIALECT: mysql
      SEMAPHORE_DB: semaphore
      SEMAPHORE_PLAYBOOK_PATH: /tmp/semaphore/
      SEMAPHORE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: '${SEMAPHORE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}'
      SEMAPHORE_ADMIN_NAME: '${SEMAPHORE_ADMIN_NAME}'
      SEMAPHORE_ADMIN_EMAIL: '${SEMAPHORE_ADMIN_EMAIL}'
      SEMAPHORE_ADMIN: '${SEMAPHORE_ADMIN}'
      SEMAPHORE_ACCESS_KEY_ENCRYPTION: '${SEMAPHORE_ACCESS_KEY_ENCRYPTION}'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
volumes:
  semaphore-mysql:
```

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edeDa.png)

```
10:17:50 PM
Task 30 added to queue
10:17:53 PM
Started: 30
10:17:53 PM
Run TaskRunner with template: Activate ufw
10:17:53 PM
Preparing: 30
10:17:53 PM
installing static inventory
10:17:53 PM
No collections/requirements.yml file found. Skip galaxy install process.
10:17:53 PM
No roles/requirements.yml file found. Skip galaxy install process.
10:17:59 PM
10:17:59 PM
PLAY [Installiere und konfiguriere UFW Firewall] *******************************
10:17:59 PM
10:17:59 PM
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
10:18:06 PM
ok: [IP-Address]
10:18:06 PM
TASK [Installiere UFW] *********************************************************
10:18:06 PM
10:18:10 PM
ok: [IP-Address]
10:18:10 PM
10:18:10 PM
TASK [Erlaube Port 22 (SSH)] ***************************************************
10:18:12 PM
fatal: [IP-Address]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "commands": ["/usr/sbin/ufw status verbose"], "msg": "ERROR: You need to be root to run this script\n"}
10:18:12 PM
10:18:12 PM
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10:18:12 PM
IP-Address : ok=2 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
10:18:12 PM
10:18:12 PM
Running playbook failed: exit status 2
```

Comment: Do you need to enter a password when becoming sudo? If so then you need to pass the word to ansible when running the playbook `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -K`. And if you only specify become the playbook will elevate to root, maybe you also need to specify the sudo user with the directive `become_user`

Answer (score 0):

To help you troubleshooting what's really happening, could you post the result of the playbook execution, the error at the end ?

You can also add just after "become" to be sure:

```
become_method: sudo
become_user: root
```

When you execute the playbook you could add move verbose output adding : `-v` or `-vv` or `-vvv` or even `-vvv` to show the whole behaviour of the playbook.

Comment: I have added the logs in the post above, I wanted to do it without needing the root user. On the remote server, it works when I just put a sudo before the command and it doesn't ask for a password

Comment: The `ERROR:` is pretty explicit : You need to be root to run this script. This because you need to be root to operate changes on the firewall.

Comment: So there is no option to do that with a sudo user? Is it better to use shell commands directly? example: shell: sudo ufw status

Comment: It seems to be a misunderstanding : even if you are a simple user (in sudo group or with sudo rights) you do the commands as root user using sudo mechanism. If you use the shell commands instead of the modules provided by ansible you can't get benefits of idempotency and "ok" status if the firewall is alrealdy in desired state. In other words : the "become" statement is equivalent to "sudo".